# Kubernetes: Dynamically identify node and taint

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application pod which will be deployed on k8s cluster
But as Kubernetes scheduler decides on which node this pod needs to run

Now I want to add taint to the node dynamically where my application pod is running with NOschedule so that no new pods will be scheduled on this node

I know that we can use kubectl taint node with NOschedule if I know the node name but I want to achieve this dynamically based on which node this application pod is running

The reason why I want to do this is this is critical application pod which shouldn’t have down time and for good reasons I have only 1 pod for this application across the cluster

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rico answer.

You can use feature called [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity), this is still a beta but some functionality is already implemented.

You should add a `label` to your node, for example `test-node-affinity: test`. Once this is done you can Add the `nodeAffinity` of field `affinity` in the PodSpec.

```
spec:
...
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: test-node-affinity
            operator: In
            values:
            - test
```

This will mean the `POD` will look for a node with key `test-node-affinity` and value `test` and will be deployed there.

I recommend reading this blog [Taints and tolerations, pod and node affinities demystified](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-taints-tolerations-affinities/) by Toader Sebastian.

Also familiarise yourself with [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) from Kubernetes docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the node where your pod is running with something like this:

```
$ kubectl get pod myapp-pod -o=jsonpath='{.spec.nodeName}'
```

Then you can taint it:

```
$ kubectl taint nodes <node-name-from-above> key=value:NoSchedule
```

or the whole thing in one command:

```
$ kubectl taint nodes $(kubectl get pod myapp-pod -o=jsonpath='{.spec.nodeName}') key=value:NoSchedule
```

Comment: Thanks Rico qq: if for some reason my application pod on that node is restarted will it still be allowed to be runnning on the same node or it will be evicted ?